# Jenkins java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, jenkins, garbage-collection, maven-plugin, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am currently working on creating a performance framework using jenkins and execute the performance test from Jenkins. I am using https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin this plugin. The sanity test with single user in this performance framework worked well and went ahead with an actual performance test of 200 users and within 2 mins received the error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
I tried the following in jenkins.xml

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

but it didn't work and also noted that whenever I increased the memory the jenkins service stops and had to reduce the memory to 1Gb and then the service restarts.

Had increased the memory for jmeter and java as well but no help.
In the .jmx file view results tree and every other listener is disabled but still the issue persists.

Since I am doing a POC jenkins is hosted in my laptop and high level specs as follows
System Model : Latitude E7270 Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHZ(4CPU's), ~2.5GHZ Memory : 8192MB RAM

Any help please ?

Comment: What is the error when you increase the memory (PermSize or heap?) to 2GB? Also what are the specs of the machine all this is running on?

Comment: Since I am doing a POC jenkins is hosted in my laptop and its high level specs as follows
System Model : Latitude E7270
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHZ(4CPU's), ~2.5GHZ
Memory    : 8192MB RAM
There is no error when I increase the memory to 2GB(Its only Heap I think) simply the jenkins service stops

Comment: Edit the question to add that info and the include the information about which cmd line arg you changed to increase the memory to 2GB.

Comment: Added the info and regarding the cmd line argument..its already posted in the question.

Comment: I tried this
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>                                                             
But Jenkins service and seeing this exception Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
Since 8gb of ram is available not sure why even 2GB is failing

Comment: Are you running a 32bit JVM? add -d64 to the command line

Comment: java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

Comment: My jenkins slave is using :  `java -Xmx50G -jar slave.jar`   still facing the issue. Any help here?

Answer (score 2):

The error about GC overhead implies that Jenkins is thrashing in Garbage Collection. This means it's probably spending more time doing Garbage Collection than doing useful work.

This situation normally comes about when the heap is too small for the application. With modern multi generational heap layouts it's difficult to say what exactly needs changing.

I would suggest you enable Verbose GC with the following options "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"

Then follow the advice here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/gcportal-136937.html

Comment: "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" should this be included in jenkins.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Few points to note

1. You are using the integrated maven goal to run your jmeter tests. This will use Jenkins as the container to launch your jmeter tests thereby not only impacting your work but also other users of jenkins
2. It is better to defer the execution to a different client machine like a dedicated jmeter machine which uses its own JVM with parameters to launch your tests (OR) use the one that you provide

In summary,
1. Move the test execution out of jenkins
2. Provide the output of the report as an input to your performance plug-in [ this can also crash since it will need more JVM memory when you process endurance test results like an 8 hour result file]

This way, your tests will have better chance of scaling. Also, you haven't mentioned what type of scripting engine that you are using. AS per Jmeter documentation, JSR223 with groovy has a memory leak. Please refer 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler

Try adding -Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true to see if that helps (provided you are using groovy). If you are using Java 8, there is a high chance that it is creating unique class for all your scripts in jmeter and it is increasing the meta space which is outside your JVM. In that case, restrict the meta space and use class unloading and a 64 bit JVM like

-d64 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled.

Also, what is your new generation size. -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m ? Please note jmeter loads all the files permanently and it will go directly to the old generation thereby shrinking any available space for new generation.

Comment: I am not using JSR223 sampler.
regarding specifying or modifying new generation size do I need to specify in the jmeter I have installed in my laptop ? and I don't understand quite on the suggestion of moving test execution out of jenkins and provide the report as an input to plugin ? can you please elaborate on these aspects ?

Comment: When you use the jmeter maven plug-in, execution uses the jenkins JVM process and the jmeter classes and everything is loaded within jenkins. This is a poor model to scale since you are using jenkins as your controller host to run the test. You should add a jenkins slave (another windows machine with jmeter installed) and should run the test from the jenkins master to the slave. Jenkins master can connect to a slave and run windows batch script. Use jmeter command line interface to run your test and use CmdRunner to process your results.

Comment: And yes - all GC tuning that you do in your current model will be for the jenkins JVM since maven plug-in runs within the jenkins JVM. You should set the new generation on jenkins JVM just like how you have increased the heap size